# Python, Selenium e PhantomJs

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Estou utilizando o Selenium com Python e o PhantomJS. Quero clicar em um botão 
da página do youtube, mas sempre da um erro. Alguém pode me ajudar? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o código que já tens, e onde é o erro? Qual é o botão? É impossivel ajudar-te se não disponibilizas mais informação. Bem vindo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: É o botão "Mostrar Mais" que fica na parte lateral. O código é esse: "driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyWX8hdknvU")

driver.find_element_by_class_name("yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-expander")

Comment: O que ele te falou é que você está tentando utilizar um nome de classe que possui espaços... tornando ela uma "compound class" ou "classe composta".. Tente usar outro seletor para pegar uma classe simples... como por exemplo `b = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="yt-uix-button-content"')` e depois dê um click no objeto selecionado utilizando `b.click()`